# C program to find Union and intersection

Tags: c

following is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void arrays()
{
    int i,n,j;
    printf("Enter the size of the arrays:\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    int a1[n];
    int a2[n];
    int intersection[2*n], unions[n];
    printf("Enter elements of the first array:\n");

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a1[i]);
    }
    printf("Enter elements of the second array:\n");
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a2[j]);
    }
    int indexs = -1, indexu = -1;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            unions[++indexu] = a1[j];
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            if(a1[i] == a2[j])
            {
                intersection[++indexs] = a2[j];
            }
            else
            {
                unions[++indexu] = a2[j];
            }
        }
    }

    printf("Intersection:\n");
    printf("Union:\n");
    for(i = 0; i < indexs; i++)
        printf("%d",intersection[i]);
    for (j = 0; j < indexu; j++)
        printf("%d" ,unions[j]);
}
```

Right now, I am having the trouble to find the union and intersection. I am trying to fix my loops, but I cannot find where is the problem
The way I am doing it is to first compare the first array with second array. Since union means all the elements in both array. then second is to find the duplicated number will go to intersection first. or if there is no element that stored in the union. it will go to union array too.
Can anyone help?
Thanks

Comment: so, what kind of output does your code produce

Comment: Enter the size of the arrays:
2
Enter elements of the first array:
2 3
Enter elements of the second array:
3 4
Intersection:
Union:
232334
it will not show intersection

Comment: Why is the `intersection` array twice the size of the `union` array?

Comment: For starters, the nested loop (third one in the code) will produce output into `unions` that goes well-beyond its defined limits and into the land of **undefined behavior**.  This loop-pair will dump `n*n` items into `unions`, an array only `n` wide. Compounding the damage already done, this further extends beyond that by not resetting `indexu` before entering the *fourth* loop, writing even further into the UB quagmire. And *all* of this would be easily spottable if you ran this *in a debugger*.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the problem, but I noticed the code that populates unions[] is using two for loops for no good reason.  You might want to remove one loop.

Comment: Other issues: (1) Your first union loop shouldn't be a double loop, just a single loop, (2) when you compute the additional union items, you are including them if the element mismatches ANY ONE of the other elements, whereas you should include it only if it mismatches ALL of the other elements, and (3) your final print loops should be `<= indexu` and `<= indexs`, not just `<`.

Comment: OK I will take a look a again for my code Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the problems is in your output part.

```
printf("Intersection:\n");
printf("Union:\n");
for(i = 0; i < indexs; i++)
    printf("%d",intersection[i]);
for (j = 0; j < indexu; j++)
    printf("%d" ,unions[j]);
```

This code snippet prints out both `"Intersection:\n"` and `"Union:\n"` before printing array contents. That's why you think *it will not show intersection*.

The correct code should be:

```
printf("Intersection:\n");
for(i = 0; i <= indexs; i++)
    printf("%d",intersection[i]);
printf("\n");
printf("Union:\n");
for (j = 0; j <= indexu; j++)
    printf("%d" ,unions[j]);
printf("\n");
```

Comment: Even with this changed, it still doesn't show any intersections due to other issues.